# Within Google apps script, what replaces Utilities.sleep() to prevent double clicks?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, wait

I'm writing an add-on within Google Docs Script.  From a sidebar, it writes info into the Doc, not a spreadsheet.  Depending on connection speeds, the Doc is updated between <1 sec and 5 secs with the info.

My issue is with user double clicks.  I can disable the button; however, the script takes less than a second to complete, yet the Doc is updated in > 1 sec.  The finished script enables the button.  The user clicks the button again and the script attempts to write the info for the first time.  The end result is a double entry.

My solution thoughts were: 1. a wait or pause 2. a callback function or 3. Locks.

Issues: 
Callback: I couldn't figure out what event/input I could use to tell the script to unlock the button now.  I could do an infinite loop that constantly checks forever until the Doc has been updated, but that didn't seem like a solid solution.
Lock: There isn't anything there to simply just wait.  It can wait for the function to become available, but that isn't a problem.  The problem is the script is done to fast relative to the Doc update.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.  I didn't realize the .withSuccessHandler also waited for the Doc to be updated.  I assumed it only waited for the .saveSettings(settings) to finish.  Now the SuccessHandler(enablesButton) at the appropriate time to prevent double clicks.

```
        google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onFailure).withSuccessHandler(enableButton)
               .saveSettings(settings);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think of this solution:

Each time the script is called, you compare document's current text with the text which was passed to your script on the previous call.

Some pseudo code:

```
var previousText = "";

function addEntry() {
    var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
    var currentText = body.getText();

    if (currentText === previousText) {
        // Enable button here
        return;
    }

    // Add entry to document AND currentText
    // ...
    // ...

    previousText = currentText; // Save the text for future checks

    // Enable button here
}

function onButtonClick(e) {
    addEntry();
    // Disable button here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, Vyascheslav.  I appreciate it.

Does the addEntry() function loop or does it WAIT for currentText === previous Text?  If so, I don't understand and I want too.

The problem is the script for the currentText has completed; however, the Doc has not updated yet.  It is kind of like the Doc needs a "refresh" time to reflect the currentText.  Does that make sense?

If your example loops until currentText === previousText is a TRUE statement, then that would work.  But I don't see the 'looping' part.  Could you explain, please.  thx.